# How do I make a full screen grid in .net Maui?

Tags: c#, xaml, maui

I am trying to make a page which has a top row (toolbar), main content in the middle, then a status bar along the bottom of the screen. If the main content is too large then I want it to scroll. Should be easy - right?

Below is the XAML I have been using but just can't seem to get it to work. More accurately - I can't get it to work on iOS. It works fine on Android but in iOS it just expands off the bottom of the screen so I can't see it.

Any suggestions?

```xml
 <Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="100"/>
        <RowDefinition />
        <RowDefinition Height="100"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <BoxView Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="0" Color="Green"/>

    <Label Text="Row 0, Column 0" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center" />

    <BoxView Grid.Row="1" Color="Teal" />

    <ScrollView Grid.Row="1" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
        <StackLayout>
            <Label  Text="Row 1, Column 0" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center" />
            <Label  Text="Row 1, Column 0" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center" />
            <Label  Text="Row 1, Column 0" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center" />
            <Label  Text="Row 1, Column 0" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center" />
            <Label  Text="Row 1, Column 0" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center" />
            <Label  Text="Row 1, Column 0" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center" />
            <Label  Text="Row 1, Column 0" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center" />
            <Label  Text="Row 1, Column 0" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center" />
            <Label  Text="Row 1, Column 0" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center" />
            <Label  Text="Row 1, Column 0" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center" />
            <Label  Text="Row 1, Column 0" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center" />
            <Label  Text="Row 1, Column 0" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center" />
            <Label  Text="Row 1, Column 0" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center" />
            <Label  Text="Row 1, Column 0" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center" />
            <Label  Text="Row 1, Column 0" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center" />
            <Label  Text="Row 1, Column 0" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center" />
            <Label  Text="Row 1, Column 0" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center" />
            <Label  Text="Row 1, Column 0" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center" />
            <Label  Text="Row 1, Column 0" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center" />
            <Label  Text="Row 1, Column 0" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center" />
            <Label  Text="Row 1, Column 0" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center" />
            <Label  Text="Row 1, Column 0" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center" />
            <Label  Text="Row 1, Column 0" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center" />
            <Label  Text="Row 1, Column 0" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center" />
            <Label  Text="Row 1, Column 0" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center" />
            <Label  Text="Row 1, Column 0" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center" />
            <Label  Text="Row 1, Column 0" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center" />
            <Label  Text="Row 1, Column 0" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center" />
            <Label  Text="Row 1, Column 0" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center" />
            <Label  Text="Row 1, Column 0" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center" />
            <Label  Text="Row 1, Column 0" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center" />
            <Label  Text="Row 1, Column 0" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center" />
            <Label  Text="Row 1, Column 0" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center" />
            <Label  Text="Row 1, Column 0" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center" />
            <Label  Text="Row 1, Column 0" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center" />
            <Label  Text="Row 1, Column 0" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center" />
            <Label  Text="Row 1, Column 0" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center" />
            <Label  Text="Row 1, Column 0" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center" />
            <Label  Text="Row 1, Column 0" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center" />
            <Label  Text="Row 1, Column 0" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center" />
            <Label  Text="Row 1, Column 0" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center" />
            <Label  Text="Row 1, Column 0" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center" />
            <Label  Text="Row 1, Column 0" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center" />
        </StackLayout>
    </ScrollView>
    <BoxView Grid.Row="2"  Color="Red" />
    <Label Grid.Row="2" Text="Row 2, Columns 0 and 1" HorizontalOptions="Center" VerticalOptions="Center" />
</Grid>
```

Comment: The `*AndExpand` options are deprecated and shouldn't be used in MAUI (they only still exist for compatibility reasons but may be removed in the future). They also only ever worked within a `StackLayout`. Although it probably won't solve your problem, you should remove the `FillAndExpand` on the ScrollView. A ScrollView automatically takes all the available space, IIRC. You can also change the `RowDefinitions` and inline it using an attribute instead: `<Grid Grid.RowDefinitions="100,*,100">`. This means that the Row at Index 1 will take all the available space that is left in the Grid.

Comment: There seems to be a bug related to placing a ScrollView inside a Grid on iOS: https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues/15163

Comment: Thanks, yes looks like a bug. BTW I have seen a couple of times advice that AndExpand is no longer supported, but I noticed that when I remove it the layout changes so I need it in there.

Comment: *Deprecated* doesn't mean that it's not working anymore. It means that it will be removed at any time in the future, because there is a better alternative. It's only still "supported", as you say, for compatibility reasons. You shouldn't rely on it, though, because once it's removed, your UI will break.

Comment: That's the bit I don't understand though. I rely on it at the moment because there is no alternative. If I remove it then the layout doesn't work and there are no other options to make it work. It's just another Maui problem on top of the very large amount of problems.

Comment: Yes, there is an alternative. You can use a Grid with `RowDefinitions="*,auto"`, for example. The star-notation means that the first row will take all the available space and the second row sizes itself to the content. This would achieve the same as `EndAndExpand` for example. Of course, in this case, it won't work, because of the aforementioned bug. However, in general the replacement for StackLayouts with the `*AndExpand` options is to use a Grid with the `*` for rows and columns, which is supposed to be more performant than a StackLayout.

Comment: That doesn't work either. I am pretty sure I have tried all the various combinations that 'should' work. Anyway looks like it is a known bug so no point in me fighting against it.

Comment: In this particular case, yes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ewerspej's comment on question links to the known issue.

Until this is fixed, a work-around is to set a numeric height on the grid row.

You'll have to manually subtract the heights of other content. In your case, subtract 200 from the screen height:

```xml
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="100"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="{Binding ScrollViewRowHeight, Source={RelativeSource Self}" />
        <RowDefinition Height="100"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
```

code-behind:

```cs
  public double ScrollViewRowHeight { get; set; }

  ...
  // constructor
  public MyPageNameHere()
  {
      InitializeComponent();

      var screenHeight = Microsoft.Maui.Devices.DeviceDisplay.MainDisplayInfo.Height;
      ScrollViewRowHeight = screenHeight - 200;

      ...
  }
```

Comment: Thanks. The code above didn't work in my case as is, but sent me on the right track. I am now setting height in code and it works on both platforms. I guess I will stick with this until they fix the bug.